flutter video URL return 403 forbidden
flutter, video URL return 403 forbidden and work fine when I tested it with online URL video player
Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$InvalidResponseCodeException: Response code: 403
the package I used is video_player,
-- video URL is temporary link
how online URL video player handle the link and play video normally and in flutter 403 forbidden
